# Securing JSON posts from PhoneGap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova

I am trying to develop my first PhoneGap application, using MVC.NET to serve the JSON to the application. I am though in doubt how I can secure the controllers on my MVC.NET application so only PhoneGap applications can post to my server.

I e.g. have a settings controller where the user can update his/her settings, but how would I make sure that no one tampers with it?

I had plans to use the deviceID as the userid, so the user doesn't have to create an account to login, but does this rule out the possibility to make it secure, since I don't Authenticate the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same sort of authentication/authorization/security mechanisms that you would for any other web site. This means that authorization information shouldn't be passed in the clear (use SSL, encrypted cookies).  You should choose authentication information that is difficult to guess or impersonate (user id/reasonable password; I'm guessing device id might be less secure if it's broadcast regularly).  You could store this information on the phone, but with varying levels of security, i.e., if someone gets physical access to the phone it's likely that they would be able to access the credentials you store.

You might want to look at the security wiki for more detail/information: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43660891/Security

Comment: I was hoping that I somehow could check if the request came from a mobile device (I know this could be hacked as well). I guess I need to implement a user login, and use SSL to communicate between the phone and webserver.

Comment: @Dofs I would give that a qualified "yes."  You could store the the credentials once entered (various phones might handle that differently), then authenticate on behalf of the user when the app starts.  You just need to be aware of the potential security issues.  Depending on the app device id might be ok, but then the person would lose whatever you have stored when they switch phones.  I'd find an app that you think has a reasonable mechanism for your needs and try to mimic that, being cognizant that your backend web site can easily get requests from anywhere.